# How do i create a repeatable control with multiple fields in Infopath Designer 2013?

Tags: infopath

What I'm trying to do is create a repeatable control with a textbox field for "Email", and drop-down list box for "Email Type". So if I add someone who has more than one email i can just add a new section for the email and email type otherwise if they only have one email I don't have to change anything.

Is there any way to create a repeatable control with multiple fields in infopath designer 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on an earlier version of InfoPath but I would guess that you should be able to:

1. Add a repeating section
2. Add a text box inside the section
3. Add a drop-down inside the section

Is this not sufficient?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to delete this yesterday. I ended up figuring out yesterday. I ended up creating a group and putting the two field in the group, then making the group "repeating" in the group properties.